# Why am I able to rebind a reference after its initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

According to C++ Primer, by Stanley B. Lippman, Josée Lajoie, and Barbara E. Moo:

> Once initialized, a reference remains bound to its initial object. There is no way to rebind a reference to refer to a different object.

How, then, am I seemingly able to rebind the reference I initialized to another object in the following code?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
     int num1 = 10;
     int num2 = 20;

     int &rnum1 = num1;

     std::cout << rnum1 << std::endl;   // output: 10

     rnum1 = num2;

     std::cout << rnum1 << std::endl;   // output: 20

     return 0;
}
```

From my understanding num1 and num2 are two different objects.
The same type, yes, but two completely different objects.

Comment: Nice question; yes this is really confusing!

Comment: It's only confusing if you think of references as hidden pointers

Comment: @M.M Which in doing so would make you a very naughty boy.

Comment: This is the reason I dislike references from C++ and prefer plain old pointers in C. It is more explicit.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: For me they are most useful in their `const` guise as function parameters.

Comment: You didn't collect enough evidence to suggest a rebound reference (`rnum1 == num2` says nothing about identity). Look at the value of `num1` as well, and examine `rnum1` after, say, `num2 = 30`.

Comment: Add some code to show the values of `num1` and `num2` before and after the assignment to `rnum1`. Then add more code to change the value of `num2` and look at those values again.

Answer (score 7):

`rnum1 = num2;` is not rebinding the reference.

It is setting `rnum1` (and therefore `num1`) to the *value* of `num2`.

Answer (score 4):

`rnum1` is another name for `num1`

when you write `rnum1 = ...` it is if you were to write `num1 = ...`, because `rnum1` is another name for `num1`.

So the reference itself is not rebound to another variable, what you have here is simple assignment of `num1`.

To really prove it , you can print the memory addresses of `num1`, `num2` and `rnum1`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
     int num1 = 10;
     int num2 = 20;

     int &rnum1 = num1;

     std::cout << rnum1 << std::endl;   // output: 10

     rnum1 = num2;

     std::cout << rnum1 << std::endl;   // output: 20
     std::cout << &num1 << " " << &rnum1 <<" "<< &num2 << std::endl;
     return 0;
}
```